# Elaboration of Möbius inversion formula.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

The Möbius Inversion Formula states:

Let $F$ and $f$ be two number-theoretic functions related by the formula,
$$F(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} f(d),$$ Then, $$f(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d) F(n/d) = \sum_{d\mid n} \mu(n/d)F(d).$$

But I do not know how the 2 sums mentioned in the conclusion of the theorem are the same, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: You just substitute d by n/d and use the fact that this substitution is involutive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $d$ is a divisor of $n$, so is $n/d$. Since $d$ runs through all divisors of $n$, both expressions are one and the same.

Comment: could u give a proof for it please?

Comment: does not the second formula in the last line in the question must be $\sum_{d'|n} \mu(n/d) F(d')$ instead of the one given above if we substitute $d'$ instead of $d$ in the first formula?

Comment: @hopefully It would be $\sum_{d'|n} \mu(n/d') F(d')$. Since $d'$ is a dummy variable, we can change it back to  $d $ and obtain  $\sum_{d|n} \mu(n/d) F(d)$.

Comment: No if we replace d by d' in the first formula it would not be as you said in your first sentence in your previous comment. I think it would be as I said in my previous comment.

Comment: I mean take this formula $\sum_{d\mid n} \mu(d) F(n/d)$ and put in it d' instead of d..... you will get $\sum_{d'\mid n} \mu(d') F(n/d')$ which is equal $\sum_{d'\mid n} \mu(n/d) F(d)$ which is not the second formula given.

Comment: I am sorry you were correct

Answer (score 2):

Example:

For $n=9$ the first sum is
$$\mu(1)F(9)+\mu(3)F(3)+\mu(9)F(1)$$
and the second
$$\mu(9)F(1)+\mu(3)F(3)+\mu(1)F(9)$$

Can you see the pattern?